# Texture Filtering

Tags: opengl, textures

Why texture filtering is called `filtering`? As far as I understand, texture filtering means calculating the color components for the vertex from the texture texels. It can be considered as `mapping` . So where is the filtering here?

I am asking to make sure that I am not missing the concept here.

Comment: Mapping is different, that is the process of identifying a location within a texture. But actually, it is called filtering because it literally [filters the sampled signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) whenever you request a point in the texture that is not exactly the center of a texel. It is all related to sampling theory and what happens (e.g. interpolation) when you reconstruct an image from points that were not explicitly sampled. There is a finite sample rate, and you often request locations that lie somewhere inbetween actual sampled points.

Comment: Thanks Andon for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

The name just comes from the signal processing mathematical grounds, in which a [*filter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28signal_processing%29) is a function that somehow alters an incoming signal, by removing certain features or extracting others.

Applied to the discrete signals, and to the image processing in particular, and to the texture world in particular, a *filter* is just the algorithm that determines the color of a requested part of a texture. The requested part might be smaller than a texel (... *sample*), in which case you need a magnification filter; or bigger than a texel, in which case you need a minification filter. OpenGL allows you to set both of them.

These days this process gets called *sampling*, by the way (and textures store *samples*). For instance, GLSL has `sampler<N>D` objects, and OpenGL 3.3 has [Sampler Objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object). This nomenclature is closer to the process of extracting discrete parts from a continuous medium (nonetheless, sampler objects use filters to extract the requested fragment).